# Fast way of getting difference between 2 objects

Tags: javascript, performance, object, difference

Because my code will need to run this a lot, **I need a very fast code** to get the difference between 2 objects. Deleted properties should have a value of "deleted".

Example:

Object 1

```
{a: "hi", b: "hi", c: {o: "hi", p: "hi",}, d: ["hi", "bye"]}
```

Object 2

```
{a: "hi", b: "bye", c: {o: "bye",}, e: "new"}
```

Result

```
{b: "bye", c: {o: "bye", p: "deleted"}, d: "deleted", e: "new"}
```

Comment: how to process  `d: ["hi", "bye"]` when for example only `'bye'` is deleted?

Comment: What happens for `o1 = { a: [ { "foo": 1}]}` and `o2 = { a: [{"bar": 2}]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use some recursive function to handle objects. It's not clear whether you need to handle arrays too

```js
const old = {a: "hi", b: "hi", c: {o: "hi", p: "hi",}, d: ["hi", "bye"]}
const cur = {a: "hi", b: "bye", c: {o: "bye", f: "new"}, e: "new"};

const diff = (old, cur, result = {}) => {

  for(const k in cur){
    if(Object.is(old[k], cur[k])){
      continue;
    }
    if(cur[k].__proto__ === Object.prototype){
        diff(old[k], cur[k], result[k] = {});  
    }else{
      result[k] = cur[k];
    }
  }
  for(const k in old){
    if(!(k in cur)){
      result[k] = 'deleted';
    }
  }
  return result;

};



console.log(diff(old, cur));
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that properties may be added too

Comment: @hmmmm add this to your code and i'll add it to the answer